# Problem setting up Direct X for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx, linker

I've downloaded Direct X SDK from the microsoft website but when I try to compile my code i'm getting this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl initD3D(struct HWND__ *)" (?initD3D@@YAXPAUHWND__@@@Z)    C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Tutorial\Tutorial\Tutorial.obj    Tutorial
```

I have added Direct X to my C++ build directories like that:

```
$(DXSDK_DIR)include
$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64
```

I've googled it and found out that most of the time people were forgetting this line:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")
```

But it's there for me here are my includes and lib:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm using Visual studio 2010 Professional on win7 x64

Comment: Try removing that `pragma` and including appropriate libs via `Additional Dependencies` in project settings (`Linker`)

Comment: Nope, i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then probably the problem is about your library (it could be wrong version or something like that, not sure, but probably this could be the particular problem of your 64bit system). Try to check (via ctrl-q, for example in total commander) which methods does your library export and try to find `_Direct3DCreate` among them. Also, does your code have something from the library except that `Direct3DCreate` call?

Comment: (If yes, you should also receive that `unresolved` stuff for other methods too)

Answer (score 4):

Ok i've found the solution i've changed x64 to x86 in the build path. I was originally developping this project on a 32 bits machine so I guess the libraries weren't compatible. thanks for the help.

Comment: Aye don't try and link an x64 library with an x86 binary.